# Mongoose population issue at express.js

Tags: express, mongoose

Hello evryone i have issue last 2 days tryin to populate reviews on company list.

Im trying to get list of all companys with their reviews.

Every review is assigned to company Id.

On postman response i get empty array : []

Here is the code im having isuses with;

Company Model:

```js
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var slug = require("mongoose-slug-generator");
    
    mongoose.plugin(slug);
    
    var CompanySchema = new Schema({
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        slug: { type: String, slug: "title" },
        address: {type: String, required: true},
        totalRating: {type: Number, required: false},
        description: {type: String, required: false},
        facebookLink: {type: String, required: false},
        twitterLink: {type: String, required: false},
        googleLink: {type: String, required: false},
        linkedIn:{type: String, required: false},
        instagramLink:{type: String, required: false},
        contactNumber:{type: Number, required: false},
        website:{type: String, required: false},
        email:{type: String, required: false},
        review: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review"}],
        user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    }, {timestamps: true});
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Company", CompanySchema);
```

Review Model :

```js
            var mongoose = require("mongoose");
        
        var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        
        var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
            title: {type: String, required: true},
            description: {type: String, required: true},
            rating: {type: String, required: true},
            user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
            company: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Company"}
        }, {timestamps: true});
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
```

And where i populate it :

```js
    exports.companyList = [
        function (req, res) {
            try {
    
                Company.
                    find({id: req._id}).
                    populate("review").
                    then((companies)=>{
                        if(companies.length > 0){
                            return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, "Uspješno 1", companies);
                        }else{
                            return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, "Uspješno 2", []);
                        }
                    });
            } catch (err) {
                //Baci error 500...
                return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, err);
            }
        }
    ];
```

Ive tryed evrything thanks infront.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in your `Company Model`

```
review: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review"}]
```

to

```
review: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review"}
```

---

Then when you try to populate, I assume you either pass the `_id` of the company in your `params` or `body` of the `request`, so most likely:

```
req.params.id
```

or

```
req.body.id
```

---

the actual function:

```
module.exports = {
  fncName: (req, res) => {
    Company.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate({
      path: 'review',
    })
      .exec((err, company) => {
      if (!err) {
        if(companies.length > 0){
          return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, "Uspješno 1", companies);
        }else{
          return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, "Uspješno 2", []);
        }
      }else {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I am not sure how you register the router but it could look something like this:

```
const router = require ('express-promise-router')();
router.get('/get-company', nameOfTheController.fncName);
```

---

Note: to populate review from `Company Model` you do not necessarily need this line in your `Review Model`:

```
company: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Company"}
```